# Controller Route not found in production environment

Tags: shopware

**The problem**: I am currently working on a custom plugin for Shopware 6 with the development template (https://github.com/shopware/development) and testing it on localhost.

The goal is to use my plugin for our online shop which runs on the production environment (https://github.com/shopware/production)

My problem is that my plugin works exactly like I want on localhost, but not anymore if I upload it to our production environment.

Example: I wrote a new API Controller that introduces a new Route, which does basically the same as the SyncController does but with a little extra logic.

```
 * @Route("/api/v{version}/_action/my-extension/sync",
 *     name="api.action.my-extension.sync",
 *     methods={"POST"}
 * )
```

The entry in my services.xml:

```
     <service id="MyExtension\Api\Controller\CustomSyncController" public="true">
        <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Framework\Api\Sync\SyncService"/>
        <argument type="service" id="serializer"/>
        <call method="setContainer">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
        </call>
    </service>
```

The entry in my routes.xml:

```
<import resource="../../Api/Controller" type="annotation" />
```

As I understand it, that should be sufficient to let Shopware 6 know what my Route is and I should be able to send my POST Request to this Route.

**Everything works fine on localhost.**

**My question:**
What steps do I have to take to use this plugin on our production environment, because I always get this message on production:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"0","status":"404","title":"Not Found","detail":"No route found for \u0022POST \/api\/v3\/_action\/my-extension\/sync\u0022"}]}
```

What I tried to make it work:

1. just ZIP the folder custom/plugins/MyExtension and upload my plugin to production.
2. upload my plugin to localhost, run ./psh.phar administration:build, download the folder from localhost, ZIP this folder and upload it to production.
3. upload my plugin to localhost, run ./psh.phar administration:build and ./psh.phar storefront:build, download the folder from localhost, ZIP this folder and upload it to production.
4. After uploading my plugin also start the script "build-administration.sh" and "build-storefront.sh" on our production environment.

Currently I am lost, because I can´t understand what steps are necessary to get the same results in the production environment that I get on localhost.

Comment: Did you activate the module?

Answer (score 1):

Meybe you try this in your routes.xml.

```
<import resource="../../Api/Controller/**/*.php" type="annotation" />
```

Also the `routes.xml` file must be located in `src/Resources/config/routes.xml` in your plugin.

Also you didn't mentioned the installation of the plugin, so you also have to install and activate it.